# How to Get the absolute url of a SharePoint library file

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I have this current link with me:

```
https://demo.com/:b:/s/sites/EXhKcRUvGA9NlAIi0BMMfdCFHNVxtTvA7lYEwj0g?e=SS3ym2
```

How to get the absolute URL of a SharePoint library file using URL like below?

I want use REST API to this URL:

```
https://demo.com/sites/sieName/DocLib8/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id={id}.
```

Comment: (if it is one-timer) - I'd go to this link in browser and get file then use "details" to get real file path...

Comment: My regret is that there are many :(

Comment: Try the following endpoint: 

`https://<url>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/<name>/DocLib8/<fileName>')/ListItemAllFields`

 The absolute URL of the file can be accessed with `response.d.EncodedAbsUrl`